# LegendGraphic and Label placement

Tags: geoserver, labeling, getlegendgraphic

I have to style some Rasters with SLD and get the legend from Geoserver to show it in my webapp.

By default, labels are placed right to the Color Ramp.

[image]

Is there any option, by using **SLD** or maybe any parameters I can pass to the **request** for the legend, so that I can place labels at some other position?

So far I tried with `LEGEND_OPTIONS`, but it seems there's no parameter that fits my needs.

```
.../geoserver/temper/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&LAYER=temper:DICIEMBRE2017&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=5&transparent=true&LEGEND_OPTIONS=fontSize:12;fontStyle:bold;fontColor:0xFFFFFF;dpi:180;
```

Comment: you can try it using `legend_options` parameter in your request and pass values http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FranciscoRaga, I've already tried it with no luck.

Comment: Only for clarify,need a dinamic legend?you can put the labels on the left but i understand that need only one sld and change this position in each request,its okey?

Comment: It would be better for me if I could do this with a request parameter, because I've so many SLDs, one for each raster source, and I have a lot. But if the only way is to change the SLD it's okay.

Comment: i'm not sure but i think that is not possible,check this options https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/GSIP-146

Comment: Thank you again, I played with some parameters like (mx, my, dx, dy, absoluteMargins) using negative values, but still not be possible to place it right.